# Change color of text that is inside a template literals

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code and the result:

```js
let upperGuideText = document.getElementById("upperGuideText");

function printGuide(guide){
   upperGuideText.innerHTML = `${guide}`;
};

printGuide('I was ... to earth.');
//printGuide('I was sent to earth.');
```

```html
<div class = "upperGuideContainer">
 <p id="upperGuideText" class="upperGuide"></p>
</div>
```

What if we want to change the color of `...` while the color of the rest of the text passed to the function remains intact?!

The desired result would be something like this:

[image]

And with `printGuide('I was sent to earth.');` we should get:

[image]

Comment: Will it always be `...` ? So if i say `This is a ... `, the `...` will be in orange as well ?

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but I don't quite get it. You always want to change the color of three consecutive dots in a string, is that it?

Comment: `printGuide('I was <span style="color:orange">...</span> to earth.');`?

Comment: Yes, I always want to change the color of three consecutive dots in a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to replace `...` by colored `...` then you may have something like this in your function:

```
function printGuide(guide){
   guide = guide.replace(/\.\.\./gi, '<span style="color: orange;">...</span>');
   upperGuideText.innerHTML = `${guide}`;
};
```

With this, every time you send a string with `...` in it, it will replace it by colored `...`

Answer (score 3):

You could split on the text you want to highlight and then join on that same text after you wrap it in `<span>` tags.

```js
let upperGuideText = document.getElementById("upperGuideText");

function printGuide(guide, coloredText){
   guide = guide.split(coloredText).join("<span style='color:orange;'>" + coloredText + "</span>");
   upperGuideText.innerHTML = `${guide}`;
};

printGuide('I was ... to earth.', '...');
```

```html
<div class = "upperGuideContainer">
 <p id="upperGuideText" class="upperGuide"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like this better if it wasn't using inline styles but one line of CSS instead, but otherwise this seems perfect for what OP wants. Also, `<em>` would probably do nicely. :)

Comment: Sure. I'd recommend applying a class (rather than an inline `style` attribute), and that could be changed within CSS going forward.  Or even could pass the class name in as part of the function if OP wants to get fancier.  But was just demonstrating the basic concept. Thank you for the feedback!